# Allocate a set of job arrays in a previously defined number of nodes

Tags: arrays, nodes, jobs, slurm, sbatch

I am trying to execute a process using 6000 samples as input, so I am trying to use job arrays in order to do so. My main problem is that those jobs allocate in every node my machine has available, and I would like to restrain the number of nodes this entire process uses so I can keep using my machine for other tasks.

When setting the SBATCH parameters, the chosen value for the -N and --ntasks parameters was 1 for both.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the number of concurrent running jobs in an array:

From https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html :

> A maximum number of simultaneously running tasks from the job array may be specified using a "%" separator. For example "--array=0-15%4" will limit the number of simultaneously running tasks from this job array to 4.